# PHP Website Basics Directory Structure

Tags: php, html, directory, structure

I have a newsletter 3rd party system.  It has been working really well however I have come across an issue which I'm hoping is a really easy fix.

So this is the root structure of my website

```
FTP SERVER
/index.php
/news.php
/shane/shane_about.php
/mailist/globals.php
/mailist/mailbar.php
/mailist/mailbar8.php
```

So I have an input box which allows me to register for a newsletter.  It works a treat on index.php and news.php however screws up the whole page on shane_about.php because its in a child directory shane.

Now the problem is in the globals.php

```
<?php 
$main_dir = "maillist/";
$website = "http://www.mysite.com/";
$relative_string="index.php?page=mail&";
$absolute_path="/hostingcompanyserver/something/something/something.com/maillist/";
$lang="lang_english.php";
```

So I changed the variable $main_dir to "../mailist/"

This then worked on the shane/shane_about.php, then index.php and news.php had the same issue (it screwed up).

I'm sure the solution is very basic, any thoughts would be appreciated.
Thanks Chris

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `$main_dir` to an absolute path.

If it's the same as `$absolute_path` you won't have this problem.

```
$main_dir = "/hostingcompanyserver/something/something/something.com/maillist/";
```

The problem at the moment is index.php and news.php look inside maillist as defined by `$main_dir`. shane_about.php looks inside /shane/maillist/.

You then told it to go up a directory to maillist with `..maillist/`. This meant shane_about.php was looking in the right place but index.php and news.php weren't.

By using an absolute path all files look in the same place.

Comment: That worked a treat, thank you for explaining it too, that made sense :)